# Django foreign-key and one-to-one access best practice

Tags: django, django-models

Say I have the following Models:

```
class User(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   ...

class Knapsack(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(
       User,
       on_delete=models.CASCADE,
       null=False
   )
   ...
```

Now say I want to access the knapsacks for a given user whose object is `my_user`. I have a couple options:

```
knapsacks = Knapsack.objects.filter(user=my_user).values()
knapsacks = my_user.knapsack.values()
```

The same question could be asked but for a one-to-one relationship instead of foreign key.

Which one is the better practice?

Answer (score 0):

Both `OneToOne` fields and `ForeignKey` fields has the same behavior, you can just call them using `user.user`. The first user is an instance of your `Knapsack` model, and the second one will be the `User` related to it